# Скачать сайт (со всеми исходниками и функционалом) имея доступ к админ панели ocStore

Tags: opencart, design, ocstore

У меня есть доступ к админ панели интернет-магазина в ocStore. Я хочу изменить дизайн сайта и не знаю как это сделать. Нужно ли мне качать сайт или кардинально изменить дизайн можно через админ панель?

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий. Под изменением дизайна можно подразумевать многое. В любом случае, я бы посоветовал бы почитать документацию для понимания возможностей.